# Filter channel entries by category with nested condition

Tags: expressionengine

How can we filter channel entries like below:

```
{exp:channel:entries category="1&2&3&(5|6)"}
```

Is it possible to use '&' and '|' together?

Comment: I recommend you ask over at [ExpressionEngine StackExchange](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested conditions isn't possible natively. [Dandy Cat](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/dandy-cat), a free plugin, will give you this exact functionality.

So for your example, you would do:

```
{exp:dandy_cat:entries categories=”(1&2&3)&(5|6)”}
    ....
{/exp:dandy_cat:entries]
```